MacOS: Mailbox external names
I am using Mail from MacOS 15.1 Sequoia.
My various mailboxes are located at ~/Library/Mail/V10
Unfortunately, they are named thought abstract names, something like
% ls -1 ~/Library/Mail/V10

242D854E-3F8C-4472-A32A-C10BC19D649C/
302921F3-C5DD-47A5-A697-1C8C05004ACB/
5F5CFD86-1E0D-4FB6-8FE0-C978C4E9071D/
6006744B-D131-49CA-883F-52CCC767DC01/
673770C6-0BF4-4AD9-AE78-220F7CB7CACC/
6F6D2A10-672C-4ED1-8993-75CFDBE998B7/
7CE2176E-5905-4DB3-AFC6-E21461D9B045/
852DD19B-CEF3-4B48-B440-04BC0CF3C66E/
C7C874FB-1371-4156-AD1F-D5758F7253AA/
MailData/

Where can I find the correspondance table between those abstract names and the actual, visible names, say: Gmail, iCloud, etc.
I search plist files at ~/Library/Mail/ and below. They contains the external names of the folders, but not of the mailboxes.
